# How to compile C++ correctly on Mac when it compiles without problems on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, macos

I am working with a C++ project written by others which compiles successfully on Linux. After I cloned it to Mac and do 'make', it gives this error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

On my Mac I have g++ installed. I then remove the -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 option from the Makefile:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -mstackrealign  -o ${NAME}.so $(SEGSRC) $(CFILE)
```

These are some definition in the Makefile:

```
CC                = /usr/bin/g++
CFLAGS    =   -D_ChaiScriptON -g -w -O0 -fPIC -shared -std=c++11
```

Does the 'c++11' mean I should install c++11 on my Mac? I have g++ installed.

I tried removing the -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 from the command, then I gives this error:

```
./CObjectRecognizer/include/commonsFun.h:15:10: fatal error: 'io.h' file not found
#include <io.h>
         ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Does the 'io.h' come from standard c library?

Comment: Note that the message came from `clang++` and _not_ `g++` [_real_ `gcc/g++`]. IIRC [and I could be wrong], `g++` gets linked to `clang++` as macOS prefers `clang` and not `gcc`. Maybe try getting it to compile under linux with `clang` first???

Comment: How did you install `g++` exactly? What happens if you run `type g++`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, this is what happens: when type 'g++', it shows: clang: error: no input files

Comment: A variation on what I mentioned before [as you surmised]: `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` is a `g++/gcc` option. `clang++` does _not_ have such an option. So, even if you're invoking `g++`, you're getting `clang++`. Also, it's strange for the makefile to do: `CC = /usr/bin/g++` instead of `CC = /usr/bin/gcc`. The usual would be: `CPP = /usr/bin/g++`

Comment: Under linux, there is `/usr/include/sys/io.h`, a linux kernel specific file. Under macOS, there probably isn't a `/usr/include/sys/io.h`. Try commenting out the `#include` and then see what symbols come back undefined (e.g. `inb`, `ioperm`, `iopl`). You may have to write a wrapper `io.h` that includes the macOS equivalent. On linux, try running `gcc` under `strace` to see where it gets `io.h` from. It may be `sys/io.h` or something else altogether. Then, look at the contents of that file.

Comment: I asked you to run `"type g++"`please, not `"g++"`

Comment: MacOSX and Linux are different operating systems. You should expect spending weeks in porting efforts. And on some Apple machines, the `g++` command might actually not be a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) but a [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler.

Comment: You can always install `GCC` on macOS: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-8-3-0/ or, with something more recent: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/. Then, you can even super easily control your environment using modules: https://www.owsiak.org/modules-as-a-convenient-way-of-choosing-build-chain-on-macos/

Comment: @MarkSetchell Here it is: type g++
g++ is /usr/bin/g++

Answer (score 1):

`C++11` is a version of C++. Unless your version of g++ is extremely old it will support C++11 without problems.

`<io.h>` is a non-standard header file. You should remove it, but unfortunately it's presence might mean that the code you are trying to compile is also non-standard. In which case you may have trouble getting the code to work in a different environment.

**EDIT** clang should have no trouble with C++11 either.

Comment: How to get it to work with 'clang' first? I can't remove it because the code has this line.

Comment: The fact that you are getting the error "fatal error: 'io.h' file not found
#include <io.h>" tells me that your compiler is accepting the argument you are  pass it, and actually starting to process the file.  You will need to search on your Mac for 'io.h' and include the path to it as an argument to clang : '-I/path/to/io.h' (note that it is a capital I (eye)).  If you can't find 'io.h' you will need to find where it comes from and install it.  (note: I have only seen 'io.h' in Windows code -- not saying it does not exist on Linux)

Comment: @marlon I meant remove it from the code. Even if your Mac has a copy of this file somewhere, there is absolutely no guarantee that it will do the same thing as the copy on Linux. It's a non-standard file after all.

Comment: @marlon There's no question that you are going to have to dig down into the code to get this code ported  If you aren't comfortable with that then you'll probably need some local help.

Answer (score 0):

here is the contents of `io.h` on linux:

Note: This seems to be a OS specific file for when running on x86-64 hardware.

```
/* Copyright (C) 1996-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#ifndef _SYS_IO_H
#define _SYS_IO_H   1

#include <features.h>

__BEGIN_DECLS

/* If TURN_ON is TRUE, request for permission to do direct i/o on the
   port numbers in the range [FROM,FROM+NUM-1].  Otherwise, turn I/O
   permission off for that range.  This call requires root privileges.

   Portability note: not all Linux platforms support this call.  Most
   platforms based on the PC I/O architecture probably will, however.
   E.g., Linux/Alpha for Alpha PCs supports this.  */
extern int ioperm (unsigned long int __from, unsigned long int __num,
                   int __turn_on) __THROW;

/* Set the I/O privilege level to LEVEL.  If LEVEL>3, permission to
   access any I/O port is granted.  This call requires root
   privileges. */
extern int iopl (int __level) __THROW;

#if defined __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ >= 2

static __inline unsigned char
inb (unsigned short int __port)
{
  unsigned char _v;

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %w1,%0":"=a" (_v):"Nd" (__port));
  return _v;
}

static __inline unsigned char
inb_p (unsigned short int __port)
{
  unsigned char _v;

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %w1,%0\noutb %%al,$0x80":"=a" (_v):"Nd" (__port));
  return _v;
}

static __inline unsigned short int
inw (unsigned short int __port)
{
  unsigned short _v;

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("inw %w1,%0":"=a" (_v):"Nd" (__port));
  return _v;
}

static __inline unsigned short int
inw_p (unsigned short int __port)
{
  unsigned short int _v;

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("inw %w1,%0\noutb %%al,$0x80":"=a" (_v):"Nd" (__port));
  return _v;
}

static __inline unsigned int
inl (unsigned short int __port)
{
  unsigned int _v;

  __asm__ __volatile__ ("inl %w1,%0":"=a" (_v):"Nd" (__port));
  return _v;
}

static __inline unsigned int
inl_p (unsigned short int __port)
{
  unsigned int _v;
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("inl %w1,%0\noutb %%al,$0x80":"=a" (_v):"Nd" (__port));
  return _v;
}

static __inline void
outb (unsigned char __value, unsigned short int __port)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %b0,%w1": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port));
}

static __inline void
outb_p (unsigned char __value, unsigned short int __port)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %b0,%w1\noutb %%al,$0x80": :"a" (__value),
            "Nd" (__port));
}

static __inline void
outw (unsigned short int __value, unsigned short int __port)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("outw %w0,%w1": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port));

}

static __inline void
outw_p (unsigned short int __value, unsigned short int __port)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("outw %w0,%w1\noutb %%al,$0x80": :"a" (__value),
            "Nd" (__port));
}

static __inline void
outl (unsigned int __value, unsigned short int __port)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("outl %0,%w1": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port));
}

static __inline void
outl_p (unsigned int __value, unsigned short int __port)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("outl %0,%w1\noutb %%al,$0x80": :"a" (__value),
            "Nd" (__port));
}

static __inline void
insb (unsigned short int __port, void *__addr, unsigned long int __count)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cld ; rep ; insb":"=D" (__addr), "=c" (__count)
            :"d" (__port), "0" (__addr), "1" (__count));
}

static __inline void
insw (unsigned short int __port, void *__addr, unsigned long int __count)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cld ; rep ; insw":"=D" (__addr), "=c" (__count)
            :"d" (__port), "0" (__addr), "1" (__count));
}

static __inline void
insl (unsigned short int __port, void *__addr, unsigned long int __count)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cld ; rep ; insl":"=D" (__addr), "=c" (__count)
            :"d" (__port), "0" (__addr), "1" (__count));
}

static __inline void
outsb (unsigned short int __port, const void *__addr,
       unsigned long int __count)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cld ; rep ; outsb":"=S" (__addr), "=c" (__count)
            :"d" (__port), "0" (__addr), "1" (__count));
}

static __inline void
outsw (unsigned short int __port, const void *__addr,
       unsigned long int __count)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cld ; rep ; outsw":"=S" (__addr), "=c" (__count)
            :"d" (__port), "0" (__addr), "1" (__count));
}

static __inline void
outsl (unsigned short int __port, const void *__addr,
       unsigned long int __count)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cld ; rep ; outsl":"=S" (__addr), "=c" (__count)
            :"d" (__port), "0" (__addr), "1" (__count));
}

#endif  /* GNU C */

__END_DECLS
#endif /* _SYS_IO_H */
```